# How to bulk update AWS Lambda Functions from C#?

Tags: c#, aws-lambda

How can I update multiple AWS Lambda Functions using the Visual Studio tool? Is there another tool that I should use?

Example use case: I have several lambda functions that utilize the same code base. I make a minor update to the code base and need to update all the lambda functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an AWS Serverless Application. This allows you  to create multiple Lambda functions in a single project which can updates all at once using a CloudFormation stack. (You can also create an API Gateway for each function.)

If you specifically want to keep each Lambda function as a separate project then there is currently no way to publish more than one Lambda function at a time. The Visual Studio tool is still new and hopefully they'll make the tools better in the future.

Outside of Visual Studio there is an [AWS CLI tool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/) with which I believe you can use to publish lambda functions (which may be good to use anyway over the Visual Studio tool). However, I have never used the CLI tool and therefore am not able to give any tips on how to use it.

Comment: I see, so I'm actually hosting the entire application inside of the lambda function. The lambda entry point really just acts as a pass through to the Mvc controllers in the .NET Core application. I was assuming each endpoint was its own Lambda function.